# How to exclude certain file types from dotnet watch run?

Tags: .net-core, msbuild, csproj, dotnet-tool

Looking to get the following setup going:

I'm working on a Blazor app, and with the official css isolation bundler. I'm using [Less](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_(stylesheet_language)) though, and installed a Less transformer which creates the required css on build.

However, running my app via `dotnet watch run`, it often ends up in an endless loop now.

The reason for this is probably that `dotnet watch run` sees a change in the `*.razor.css` files, rebuilds, and the cycle just repeats on and on.

So here's my question:

How can I configure my csproj (new Net Standard format) to exclude `**\*.razor.css` from the watch process? It would also be fine it it just disappears from my VS solution as a whole.

Comment: have you resolve the problom?

Answer (score 11):

Had a play with both answers above, but neither worked for me. I generate some files during the build and that may be why the other 2 don't work for me. According to Microsoft docs shared above (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/dotnet-watch?view=aspnetcore-3.1), to remove an item from watch you can also set it through the definition. Doing this worked for my scenario.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Remove="wwwroot\dist\**" />
    <Content Include="wwwroot\dist\**" Watch="false" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I did have to add the Content Remove as otherwise the item is declared twice and the build will fail.

Comment: Thanks! A tip: this could be more simply achieved with `<Content Update="wwwroot\dist\**" Watch="false" />`.

Comment: Another tip for anyone struggling, `dotnet watch --list` in the project dir tells you exactly what files will be watched, so you can easily test these changes.

Answer (score 1):

Please edit your **.csproj** file and add the following to it

```xml
<ItemGroup>  
    <Watch Exclude="**\*.razor.css" />
</ItemGroup>
```

More info at

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/dotnet-watch?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Hey, thanks, I already tried this - However, I got the following error: error MSB4232: Items that are outside Target elements must have one of the following operations: Include, Update, or Remove.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after coming here, ended up with:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Watch Remove="wwwroot\**\*" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Works nicely for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar set-up except but I'm using SASS. I have a custom target to execute the command `npm run sass`, so the files are being generated as part of the `dotnet build` process, which made the watch re-trigger builds in an infinite loop.

In my case, the solution I found was like the following:

1. Alter the `DefaultItemExcludes`:

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);Features/**/*.css</DefaultItemExcludes>
</PropertyGroup>
```

2. Adjust sure the css compilation target to run before `BeforeResGen` instead of `Compile` (which I was using before):

```
  <Target Name="CompileScopedScss" BeforeTargets="BeforeResGen">
    <Exec Command="npm run sass -- %(ScopedScssFiles.FullPath) %(RootDir)%(Directory)%(FileName).css --no-source-map" />
  </Target>
```

3. Include the css file and set `Watch="False"`:

```
    <ItemGroup>
      <Content Include="Features/**/*.css" Watch="False" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

I do this in a target after the previous target, but it seems to work also outside it.

Just using the `<Content Update... Watch="False" />` wasn't enough in my case. The `<Watch Remove="..." />` didn't work either in my case and I believe it could have something to do with the fact that the files are generated during the build.